# Chevy sonic 2013

Tags: chevrolet, ac, fan, cooling, sonic

Does this car have any fuse for the cooling fan? 
My car had overheated and the temperature light has come on and my AC blows out hot and the fan does not turn on.

Comment: Which engine do you have? There are differences between the 1.4 and 1.8. If you look at the underhood fuse box cover the fusible links and or fuses should be labeled.

Comment: Just in general, everything in a car will lead back to some type of fuse.  Without a fuse a simple electrical short in a bad motor or actuator could cause an electrical fire.